# Java Array/List with stable index on remove

Tags: java, android, list, dictionary, arraylist

I'm looking for a data structure like `ArrayList` which elements don't get reindexed after removing a single one from it.

As an example scenario, Consider having a list as following **psoudocode**:

```
A(0) = m
A(1) = n
A(2) = o
A(3) = p
A(4) = q
```

Using `ArrayAdapter`, issuing a `A.remove(2)` results in:

```
A(0) = m
A(1) = n
A(2) = p      // index decremented
A(3) = q      // index decremented
```

which is not my desired behaviour. I'm looking for a list/array/map/set/collection/whatever which gives a result like this:

```
A(0) = m
A(1) = n
A(3) = p      // index persisted
A(4) = q      // index persisted
```

It "can" be done using a integer counter combined with a `Map` but i'm wondering if a cleaner solution is already available.

Dirty approach using Map and integer counter:

```
HashMap<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
int indexCounter = 0;

public void insertItem(Object o){
    map.put(indexCounter, o);
    indexCounter++;
}
```

Any ideas?

Edit: 
To clearify, by `m, n, o, ...` i mean different values. These are not necessarily string and can be any kind of objects. That's a pseudocode.

More than that, Using NULL or mock values would not be an option in my case. Although, i'm looking for a general solution, not a specific one for my case. Thanks for sharing btw.

Edit 2:
Actually, im looking for a data structure, not a hack or trick. Thus, if there is not such a thing provided in Java, the correct answer to this question would be a straight conclusive "No, there isn't such a thing".

Comment: Using a `null` or NONE constant value or an array of `Optional<String>` or such.

Comment: a simple solution maybe you can keep an id inside your array and that can be reused like position.

Comment: Why you are not using array in your use case. You can increase the size of array by two if it got filled.

Answer (score 1):

> "Actually, im looking for a data structure, not a hack or trick."

That is not a valid distinction unless you can define the difference between a "data structure" and a "hack" or "trick".

In your example, you say that the data structure / API / whatever, need to give you the following after deletion of the 3rd element:

```
A(0) maps to m
A(1) maps to n
A(3) maps to p 
A(4) maps to q
```

but what you don't say is what should happen if someone asks what `A(2)` maps to.  There are multiple possible answers, but the most plausible are:

- it maps to `null`
- it maps to some distinguished `String`; e.g. `""`
- it doesn't map; e.g. you get an exception.

All of these can be represented using a thin wrapper for a `Map<Integer, String>` where the key is the element index.  You could use a `HashMap` or a `TreeMap`, depending on other requirements for this data structure.

An alternative would be to use Android's [`SparseArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) class.  This behaves like a map from `int` to `Object`, but it doesn't implement the standard `Map` API.  That allows them to use a much more compact representation than is possible using a `HashMap` or `TreeMap`.

Under the hood, `SparseArray` uses paired arrays of `int` and `Object`. It arranges that the `int` values are ordered so that they can be searched using simple binary search.  The downside is that lookup is `O(log N)` and insertion can be `O(N)`. (Check the Android source code for the details.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own method thats replaces the value at a specific index to an empty String...

```
public void resetA_AtIndex(int index)
{
   A.remove(index);
   A.add(index, "");
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in last edit, having NULL or empty string value is not a desired option. I'm looking for a data structure. This solution is not much different from the dirty solution i mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with LinkedList which would solve your purpose and won’t impact performance on removal of element like ArrayList.

You can check this link to understand whether it satisfies your needs
https://dzone.com/articles/linked-list-journey-continues